# Command Block Funkiness

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to do something with command blocks in Bedrock 1.14, and I am probably being a complete noob but my chain command blocks aren't working. And, before you yell at me, yes, I did make sure all the pointy tip things on the command blocks were facing the right way, and even made sure that my chain command blocks gamerule was on, so I've done my research and still can't figure it out. Do any of y'all have any idea why?

Comment: A picture of your setup would greatly help us ensure that your setup is correct.

Comment: ah shoot nevermind I figured it out it was a dumb problem-

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: pfft- I forgot to set my repeating command blocks to always active :facepalm: